# snowflake error in insert from view materialized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use a function avg in view materialized :

```
create or replace materialized view vue_mat_wifi_mac as
    select macadr, 
        date_trunc('HOUR', time_part) as tranche_heure,
        avg(rssi) as rssimoy,
        sum(nbcapture) as nbcapture
    from ext_iot_wifi_mac 
    group by macadr, tranche_heure;
```

and when I insert in another table the results of view

```
insert into wifi_mac_staging(rssimoy, tranche_heure, macadr, nbcapture) 
    select RSSIMOY, tranche_heure, macadr, nbcapture 
    from ext_iot_wifi_mac;`
```

i have an error:
**SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 7 invalid identifier 'RSSIMOY'**

the query select on table ext_iot_wifi_mac does work

Why ?

Comment: Can you share the schema of the table `wifi_mac_staging`? I'm wondering if it doesn't have a column with that name

Comment: Both your CREATE and INSERT statements are selecting from the same table (ext_iot_wifi_mac) so its not clear, to me, what you mean by "insert in another table the results of view". Is it your CREATE or INSERT statement that is erroring?

Answer (score 0):

If the SQL you post is the SQL you are running the problem is you second query is selecting from the wrong table. If all your column tokens are correct you SQL is the same as

```
create or replace materialized view MAT_VIEW_A as
    select MAT_VIEW_A_COL1, 
        date_trunc('hour', time_part) as MAT_VIEW_A_COL2,
        avg(rssi) as MAT_VIEW_A_COL3,
        sum(nbcapture) as MAT_VIEW_A_COL4
    from TABLE_A 
    group by MAT_VIEW_A_COL1, MAT_VIEW_A_COL2;
```

and

```
insert into TABLE_B(MAT_VIEW_A_COL1, MAT_VIEW_A_COL2, MAT_VIEW_A_COL3, MAT_VIEW_A_COL4) 
    select MAT_VIEW_A_COL1, MAT_VIEW_A_COL2, MAT_VIEW_A_COL3, MAT_VIEW_A_COL4 
    from TABLE_A;`
```

but the `TABLE_A` does not have the column `MAT_VIEW_A_COL1` so it would seem you ment to select from your MAT_VIEW_A thus your SQL should be:

```
insert into wifi_mac_staging(rssimoy, tranche_heure, macadr, nbcapture) 
    select RSSIMOY, tranche_heure, macadr, nbcapture 
    from vue_mat_wifi_mac;`
```

but it doesn't really make sense to insert into another table, all the values from a materialized view with no extra enrichment or timestamp/snapshot like extra's. As you are paying for the disk space in the materialized view. Maybe cloning it makes more sense (which I have not investigated, thus this is really what you are trying todo).

Comment: it's an example. i will have a filter on this view to insert a staging table for CDC process (stream).the subquery is correct et work.I think the problem comes from the function avg in the view (creation of 2 internal columns $SYS_FACADE). By the way, on Qlik or other tools, I have an exception also on this view (colonne rssimoy$SYS_FACADE$0 ??)